# Selectbox not set even when view object is set?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

**Hi,**

I got help with this problem a couple of days ago :

[Strange problem with ASP.NET MVC DropDownFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917727/strange-problem-with-asp-net-mvc-dropdownfor)

The solution i got worked, but now I have runned in to a simular problem with the same view and action.

This time I got the following in a partial view that is loaded in to the main view :

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ST1, Model.ShowAdTypeList1, new { @class = "dd2", @style = "width:80px;" })%>
```

This will be rendered like this :

```
<select name="ALS.ST1" id="ALS_ST1">
<option value="0">Alla</option>
<option value="1">Privata</option>
<option value="2">Företag</option>
</select>
```

I have the following code at the end of the action

```
    data.ALS.ST1 = 2;
    ModelState.Clear();
    return View(data);
```

The problem is that the dropdown is always selecting 0? When choosing value 2 manually in the dropdown the data.ALS.ST1 will be set to 2 when entering the action.

Why is it not setting the dropdown to value 2?

**Edit1:**

This is the only javascript that works with the ALS_ST1 on the entire page :

```
$('#ALS_ST1').change(function () {
            if (IsNotDblClick(this.id)) {
                document.forms['list_ad'].submit();
            }
            else
                return false;
        });
```

**Edit2**

The Model.ShowAdTypeList1 is a of the type SelectList and do not have a selection. The DropDownFore is supose to set the ST1 value to selected.

**EDIT3**

Pleas note that this partial view is in fact a template : http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/11/27/extending-asp-net-mvc-2-templates.aspx.

Comment: That title tells the reader NOTHING.

Comment: so do you set value before bind?

Comment: @Senad Meškin > I do set it in the action as you can see in my example and I am setting model.ST1 to the dropdown. I do not manipulate the ST1 property in any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rendering the dropdownlist like this:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.ST1, 
    new SelectList(Model.ShowAdTypeList1, "Value", "Text", Model.ST1), 
    new { @class = "dd2", @style = "width:80px;" }
) %>
```

This assumes that the `ShowAdTypeList1` property is an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. If it is not you might need to adjust the `Value` and `Text` arguments.

Also instead of clearing the entire modelstate I would recommend you reset only the properties that you are modifying inside your POST action:

```
ModelState.Remove("ALS.ST1");
data.ALS.ST1 = 2;
return View(data);
```

Comment: Thanks! That works, but why? And why should I not clear the ModelState?